# Error: "Cannot find reference to loads in json.py"

Tags: python, python-import, shadowing

I am a newbie to python. I am learning the how python works with json.
After writing this code in pycharm, I am getting unresolved references at several locations.
 "Import resolves to its containing file". 
"Cannot find reference to dumps in json.py "
"Cannot find reference to loads in json.py "

I am getting this error while importing json, loads() and dumps() method are called.
This is the video link from where I am learning to code python.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I&list=PL-osiE80TeTt2d9bfVyTiXJA-UTHn6WwU&index=44

Please help me in resolving this.

```
 import json

# Decoding json string to python.

# This a python string that happens to be a valid json also.

people_string = '''
{
"people": [
{
"name": "Sumedha",
"phone":"0987654312"
"City": "Middletown"
},

{
"name": "Ankit",
"phone":"9999999999"
"City": "Middletown2"
},
{
"name": "Hemlata",
"phone":"9865656475"
"City": "Chandigarh"
}
]
}
'''

# loads method loads the string.
data = json.loads(people_string)

for person in data['people']:
    print(person['name'])
    del person['phone']

new_string = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: btw: your JSON is invalid

Comment: This is not a json file but it is a python multi-line string which acts as a valid json.

Comment: Content of `people_string` is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: once your get  your code working JSON parser will tell you :)

Comment: Your multi-line string isn't valid JSON either.

Comment: Oh I missed commas, it seems to work now. Thanks .

Answer (score 8):

You named your test script `json.py`, so it's shadowing the built-in `json` module, preventing you from importing the built-in module, making `import json` try to import itself (that's what "Import resolves to its containing file" is trying to warn you about). Name your script something else (e.g. `jsontest.py`) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to appear when you have both JSON & pandas packages in the same python environment.

I found a cheap solution by having a separate project file for pandas & JSON so that I install the packages in different virtual environments.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this question is related to pandas. You may have run into a different problem. But I am very surprised if pandas is not compatible with json since there seem to be a lot of cases of the two being used together.